# Why is this MySQL Recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) Running as an Infinite Loop?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I keep looking at this and I don't know why this CTE runs until timeout.  Anyone see something I don't?

Note that InventoryTimeline.RecID is a sequential row number (1, 2, 3, ...).  I expect this query to produce three rows for each ItemNum.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (RecID, ItemNum) 
AS 
(
    SELECT
        T.RecID, 
        T.ItemNum
    FROM
        InventoryTimeline T
    WHERE
        T.RecID = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        T.RecID,
        T.ItemNum
    FROM 
        InventoryTimeline T INNER JOIN CTE ON
            T.RecID = CTE.RecID + 1 AND
            T.ItemNum = CTE.ItemNum
    WHERE 
        T.RecID <= 3
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: After more review, I see that this statement works properly when it's contained in and run as a stored procedure.  I was running it directly in the SQL window of phpMyAdmin.  Not sure what the technical difference is though.